# Raku equivalent of Java StringBuffer/StringBuilder?

Tags: raku

I need to create a big string out of a complex structure and the runtime is way too long.
Back in the `Java` times I solved similar problems using [StringBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) or [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) which greatly reduce the number of intermediate String objects needed.

Is there something similar in `Raku`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Native string arrays pretty much allow you to do that.

```
my str @parts;
@parts.push("foo")
...
say @parts.join;
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Additionally: on the MoarVM backend, when you concat strings, they are **not** actually concatenated in memory, but rather just "linked" together into a single virtual string.  Unfortunately, the moment you want to do a regular expression on a string, if *does* need to be flattened.  Which is one of the reasons regular expressions are relatively expensive.

Comment: Um, `lizmat++ for 100`.  I was actually just looking at refactoring some complex string concats and was looking for a way to improve efficiency.

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Thanks for the insights.